# typing date into jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

besides being able to select a date from jQuery datepicker widget I also want to be able to type a date into the datepicker's textfield. But every time I type a date and hit enter, datepicker overrides my entry with today's date. I can't figure out how to have datepicker accept typed in entry.

thanks,
martin

Answer (score 0):

On [the official jQuery UI Datepicker demo page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/), this just works.

If it doesn’t work for you, you could try hitting `Tab` instead of `Enter`.

Comment: Thanks Mathias,

Tab works. Thanks. The Enter doesn't though, not even on the demo page (not for me at least). 

martin

Answer (score 0):

I also needed to be able to type 1/9/06 instead of 1/9/2006 and have it saved in MySQL as 2006-09-01 not as 0006-09-01.

Here's what I came up with:

```
$(function() {
  $("#date_text_field").datepicker({
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
      date = $.datepicker.parseDate( 'm/d/yy', dateText );
      date = $.datepicker.formatDate( 'm/d/yy', date );
      $(this).val( date );
    }
  });
});
```